# Обновление tableview без reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

у меня есть таблица которая выводит случайный массив чисел при нажатии на кнопку. Мне нужно сделать так, что бы при каждом повторном нажатии кнопки, выводились новые значения в таблицу. С `reloadData()` все работает , но мне нужно сделать это без использования этого метода. Есть ли такая возможность? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Почему вам нужно сделать без использования этого метода, поясните

Answer (score 0):

Такая возможность доступна начиная с iOS 13 с появлением UITableViewDiffableDataSource и NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot.

До iOS 13 можно вычислять дифф ячеек вручную и обновлять таблицу частично через `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`, однако в вашей ситуации, когда почти все ячейки и так обновятся, смысла в этом особого нет.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете пройтись по каждой видимой ячейке с помощью метода

```swift
tableView.visibleCells
```

В массиве видимые ячейки, каждой ячейки обновляете внешний вид.
Для тех что не видимы не нужно, они не в памяти и для них вызовется метод конфигурации.